# How to read/write a boolean when implementing the Parcelable interface?

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm trying to make an `ArrayList` `Parcelable` in order to pass to an activity a list of custom object. I start writing a `myObjectList` class which extends `ArrayList<myObject>` and implement `Parcelable`.

Some attributes of `MyObject` are `boolean` but `Parcel` don't have  any method `read/writeBoolean`.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: @grunk: ArrayList already implements Serializable. Why don't you just make your custom objects Serializable?

Comment: Because all the reading i have done about passing object between activities preconise the use of parcelable instead of serialisable.

Comment: @MisterSquonk You should not use the `Serializable` interface for inter-activity communication. It is slow.

Comment: @grunk: OK, that's fair enough but until Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable value) is marked as deprecated in the docs, I'll be happy to continue using it if it makes life easier for me. Just a thought.

Comment: @Octavian: But that depends on a per-case study and is relative.

Comment: @MisterSquonk You should read up what happens when using `Serializable`. Also any class extending `ArrayList` will be `Serializable` anyway.

Comment: Does your ArrayList hold booleans?

Comment: @Octavian: Yes, I understand the different mechanisms involved and the potential inefficiency of Serializing with Android. However, my original comment asked 'why not?' and as this is case-dependent it may well be that with small serializable objects, the performance difference is sufficiently negligible to out-weigh the extra complexity of using Parcelable. Also, my original comment points out that ArrayList is serializable but in the case of ArrayList<E> then 'E' may not be but can often be made to be very easily. The OP didn't go into detail about their object so it was a simple question.

Comment: Actually there are writeBooleanArray(boolean[]), readBooleanArray(boolean[]), createBooleanArray(). But i have issues with them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463727/readbooleanarray-throws-runtimeexceptionbad-array-lengths.

Comment: in my oppinion, the architect team of android is lazy!!! whereis boolean!!!!!!!!

Comment: Complain here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5973

Comment: In __API 29__ class `Parcel` finally has `writeBoolean()` method (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#writeBoolean(boolean))

Comment: It just took 10 years :D

Answer (score 964, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it...

writeToParcel:

```
dest.writeByte((byte) (myBoolean ? 1 : 0));     //if myBoolean == true, byte == 1
```

readFromParcel:

```
myBoolean = in.readByte() != 0;     //myBoolean == true if byte != 0
```

Comment: No reason to use byte over int. byte is more verbose because of the cast: dest.writeInt(myBoolean ? 1 : 0);

Comment: Why did @SiPlus comment get so many upvotes? Neither 1, nor 0 is "loaded" at all. It makes absolutely no difference. And since when is Java a weakly-typed language?

Comment: @miguel nope - you still **have to cast**

Comment: @miguel a byte is smaller than an int (a 32-bit int is 4 bytes), so it makes more sense to use a byte if you want to maximize parcel compression.

Comment: @sotrh writing a byte just writes an int: `/**
     * Write a byte value into the parcel at the current dataPosition(),
     * growing dataCapacity() if needed.
     */
    public final void writeByte(byte val) {
        writeInt(val);
    }`

Comment: @Dallas is that from the documentation? If so then disregard my comment. Seems disingenuous for the api to have a function that says `writeByte`, but actually writes an int.

Comment: @sotrh that is a copy-paste from a source code. Open android.os.Parcel source and see for yourself.

Comment: @sotrh This is an implementation detail and is a subject to change. I guess, that's why they encourage to never use Parcelable to persist data. Different implementation will break on reading from Parcel.

Comment: Just for someone who might be trying similar thing in Kotlin..
To write:
parcel.writeByte((if (yourBooleanVariable) 1 else 0).toByte())

To read, I had to do following because apparently you cannot directly compare with != in kotlin
yourBooleanVariable =when(parcel.readByte()) { 0.toByte() -> false else -> true}

Answer (score 70):

You could also make use of the [writeValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method. In my opinion that's the most straightforward solution.

```
dst.writeValue( myBool );
```

Afterwards you can easily retrieve it with a simple cast to `Boolean`:

```
boolean myBool = (Boolean) source.readValue( null );
```

Under the hood the Android Framework will handle it as an integer:

```
writeInt( (Boolean) v ? 1 : 0 );
```

Comment: [android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ac5a0828c14eea59f2ffda85432ad1977d3e1ce0/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java) showing the "under the hood" part (l. 1219). Though a tiny bit less efficient (because of the method call and the switch) this method reads a bit more straightforward.

Comment: The code as written here will not compile. readValue requires a classloader but it's not needed for Booleans. It should read "boolean myBool = (Boolean) source.readValue(null);" Reviewers that have no idea what they're doing and rejected my edit to this answer: @hemang, jeeped, DavidRR.

Comment: @miguel That's true, fixed it :)

Comment: It's better to not mess with classLoaders for this simple task.

Answer (score 22):

you declare like this

```
 private boolean isSelectionRight;
```

write

```
 out.writeInt(isSelectionRight ? 1 : 0);
```

read

```
isSelectionRight  = in.readInt() != 0;
```

boolean type needs to be converted to something that Parcel supports and so we can convert it to int.

Comment: This causes an error, incompatible types, required boolean found int?

Answer (score 16):

AndroidStudio (using 2.3 atm), after implementing Parcelable on your class, you can simply hold your mouse pointer over your **class name** and it asks you to add the parcelable implementation:

[image]

From the four fields, it generates the following:

```
public class YourClass implements Parcelable{

String someString;
int someInt;
boolean someBoolean;
List<String> someList;

protected YourClass(Parcel in) {
    someString = in.readString();
    someInt = in.readInt();
    someBoolean = in.readByte() != 0;
    someList = in.createStringArrayList();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(someString);
    dest.writeInt(someInt);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (someBoolean ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeStringList(someList);
}

...
```

Comment: This is handy :)

Answer (score 8):

I normally have them in an array and call `writeBooleanArray` and `readBooleanArray`

If it's a single boolean you need to pack, you could do this:

```
parcel.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[] {myBool});
```

Comment: Have you ever faced problem when you need to parcel few booleans... i have. Could You please help me> ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463727/readbooleanarray-throws-runtimeexceptionbad-array-lengths. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
out.writeInt(mBool ? 1 : 0); //Write
this.mBool =in.readInt()==1; //Read
```

Answer (score 6):

Short and simple implementation in **Kotlin**, with nullable support:

Add methods to Parcel

```
fun Parcel.writeBoolean(flag: Boolean?) {
    when(flag) {
        true -> writeInt(1)
        false -> writeInt(0)
        else -> writeInt(-1)
    }
}

fun Parcel.readBoolean(): Boolean? {
    return when(readInt()) {
        1 -> true
        0 -> false
        else -> null
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
parcel.writeBoolean(isUserActive)

parcel.readBoolean()        // For true, false, null
parcel.readBoolean()!!      // For only true and false
```

Comment: @AliKazi you can't do this in 1 line statement in Java with support optional types. You should persist 3 states. I think you forget about null.

Comment: @comm1x, The IDE does not like this solution. `Cannot access "readBoolean" before superclass constructor has been called.

Comment: @comm1x I resolved the issue. In order to work the added methods must be within the [**companion object**](https://gist.github.com/AdamSHurwitz/a988681cf48bc90740b4cd6090c82c9d)

Answer (score 5):

> I suggested you the easiest way to implement Parcelable if you are using Android Studio.

Simply go to **File->Settings->Plugins->Browse Repository** and search for parcelable .See image

[image]
It will automatically create Parcelable.

And there is a webiste also for doing this. http://www.parcelabler.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could pack your boolean values into a byte using masking and shifting. That would be the most efficient way to do it and is probably what they would expect you to do.

Comment: +1. True, saving the value in a byte would be more efficient. Would you mind me editing my question to represent your idea?

Comment: You can, but what you have written isn't really what I meant. It will work but isnt the most efficient. You can pack 8 booleans into a byte using masks and boolean algebra

Comment: On most cases I agree with you, however I do have cases that creep up from time to time where I need three states that Boolean works will with. Such as an optional yes/no question. I need the null to know whether the Boolean has explicitly been specified or not.

Comment: There is no reason using byte over int, since the Parcel's `writeByte()` method directly calls `writeInt()`

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to identify the real question here. I guess it is how to deal with booleans when implementing the `Parcelable` interface.

> Some attributes of MyObject are boolean but Parcel don't have any method read/writeBoolean.

You will have to either store the value as a string or as a byte. If you go for a string then you'll have to use the static method of the `String` class called `valueOf()` to parse the boolean value. It isn't as effective as saving it in a byte tough.

```
String.valueOf(theBoolean);
```

If you go for a byte you'll have to implement a conversion logic yourself.

```
byte convBool = -1;
if (theBoolean) {
    convBool = 1;
} else {
    convBool = 0;
}
```

When unmarshalling the `Parcel` object you have to take care of the conversion to the original type.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason using String. There is no reason using byte over int, since the Parcel's `writeByte()` method directly calls `writeInt()`. The conversion logic is too verbose. Just do `writeInt(boolean ? 1 : 0)` and `boolean = readInt() != 0`

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered perfectly by other people, if you want to do it on your own.

If you prefer to encapsulate or hide away most of the low-level parceling code, you might consider using [some of the code I wrote some time ago for simplifying handling of parcelables.](https://github.com/mickbitsoftware/parceldroid)

Writing to a parcel is as easy as:

```
parcelValues(dest, name, maxSpeed, weight, wheels, color, isDriving);
```

where color is an enum and isDriving is a boolean, for example.

Reading from a parcel is also not much harder:

```
color = (CarColor)unparcelValue(CarColor.class.getClassLoader());
isDriving = (Boolean)unparcelValue();
```

Just take a look at the "ParceldroidExample" I added to the project.

Finally, it also keeps the CREATOR initializer short:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Car> CREATOR =
    Parceldroid.getCreatorForClass(Car.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for `.class.getClassLoader()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples in the Android (AOSP) sources. For example, `PackageInfo` class has a boolean member `requiredForAllUsers` and it is serialized as follows:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int parcelableFlags) {
    ...
    dest.writeInt(requiredForAllUsers ? 1 : 0);
    ...
}

private PackageInfo(Parcel source) {
    ...
    requiredForAllUsers = source.readInt() != 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For API 29 and above we can use

*writeToParcel:*

**dest.writeBoolean(booleanFlag);**

*readFromParcel:*

**booleanFlag = in.readBoolean()**

> Or We can use

writeToParcel:

**dest.writeByte((byte) (booleanFlag ? 1 : 0));**

readFromParcel:

**booleanFlag = in.readByte() != 0;**

Answer (score 0):

Since api 29, you can now use the `readBoolean()` in the `Parcel` class.
see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readBoolean() for more