# Trouble creating a Parcelable Class in Android

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I'm attempting to create a Parcelable class in Android so that I can pass a ArrayList of these objects between Activities.  I've followed very closely the examples found here on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201311/how-to-read-write-a-boolean-when-implementing-the-parcelable-interface)and in the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), but I keep getting an error on the required static field CREATOR:  **The field CREATOR cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level types**

I get this error on my class, as well as the example class cut/pasted directly from the Android docs.  There must be something unique to my situation that I'm not aware of....??  My class is given below.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Bryan

```
public class ComplaintType implements Parcelable
{
    // class data
    private int groupID = 0;
    private int id = 0;
    private String description = "";
    private boolean checked = false; // does this complaint type apply to this patient?

    // constructors
    public ComplaintType() {}       
    public ComplaintType(int _groupID, String desc, int _id, boolean ckd) {
        this.groupID = _groupID;
        this.description = desc; 
        this.id = _id;
        this.checked = ckd;}

    // getters/setters
    public int getGroupID() {return groupID;}
    public void setGroupID(int _groupID) { this.groupID = _groupID;}
    public String getDesc() {return description;}
    public void setDesc(String desc) {this.description = desc;}
    public int getID() {return id;}
    public void setID(int _id) {this.id = _id;}
    public boolean isChecked() {return checked;}
    public void setChecked(boolean ckd) {this.checked = ckd;}

    // utility functions
    public String toString() {return this.description;}
    public void toggleChecked() {checked = !checked;}

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(groupID);
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (checked ? 1 : 0));  // convert byte to a boolean (1=true, 0=false)
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ComplaintType> CREATOR // <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE
     = new Parcelable.Creator<ComplaintType>() {

        public ComplaintType createFromParcel(Parcel in){
            ComplaintType complaint = new ComplaintType();
            complaint.setGroupID(in.readInt());
            complaint.setID(in.readInt());
            complaint.setDesc(in.readString());
            complaint.setChecked(in.readByte() == 1);  // store the boolean as a byte (1=true, 0=false)
            return complaint;
        }

        @Override
        public ComplaintType[] newArray(int size) {             
            return new ComplaintType[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your class is being declared non-static inside another class, which is why it’s not allowed to have static data members. Either make it a top-level class, or declare it static.

Comment: Doh!  You were exactly right; I had it declared inside another class.  Made it a top-level class...problem went away.  I feel a bit silly now.  Thanks for the nudge, Lawrence.