# Parcelable not setting correct value for POJO field

Tags: android, retrofit, parcelable

I am using Retrofit to load data from backend. The POJO implements Parcelable. I am facing issues while reading nd writing to/from the POJO. I think it's because the field name is different from what I get from backend.  Here's the POJO:

```
        @SerializedName("poster_path")
        public String posterPath;
    ....
    private Movie(Parcel in) {
    ...
            posterPath= in.readString();
            ...

        }
...//more code
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(posterPath);

    }
```

When I get POJO through  intent.getParcelableExtra, the posterPath is null.  What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have to read the data from the `Parcel` in the exact same order you wrote it. Are you doing this?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! I fixed the order and it's working now! Thanks

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :) Don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) objects, you have to read the `Parcel` in the exact same order that you wrote it, otherwise it won't work.

So, if you wrote it like this:

```
dest.writeString("blah");
dest.writeInt(1);
```

you have to read it like this:

```
str = in.readString();
someInt = in.readInt();
```

More info on that on [this article](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development) and on [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable?rq=1), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201311/how-to-read-write-a-boolean-when-implementing-the-parcelable-interface?rq=1) here on SO also talk about `Parcelable`, with examples.