# How to implement Parcelable on my class which contains an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I just want to know how to read and write the ArrayList. I use Kotlin.

```
data class CustomerTxn(

    @field:SerializedName("txn_note")
    val txnNote: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("txn_date")
    val txnDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("amount")
    val amount: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("txn_type")
    val txnType: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("contact")
    val contact: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("transaction_images")
    var transactionImages: ArrayList<String>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("created_at")
    val createdAt: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("cashbook")
    val cashbook: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("view_type")
    val viewType: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("modified_at")
    val modifiedAt: String? = null
    ):Parcelable {
        constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readArrayList(null),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()) {
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(txnNote)
    parcel.writeString(txnDate)
    parcel.writeString(amount)
    parcel.writeString(txnType)
    parcel.writeString(contact)
    parcel.writeList(transactionImages)
    parcel.writeString(createdAt)
    parcel.writeString(cashbook)
    parcel.writeString(viewType)
    parcel.writeString(id)
    parcel.writeString(modifiedAt)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<CustomerTxn> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): CustomerTxn {
        return CustomerTxn(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<CustomerTxn?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

These lines are giving me error :

```
parcel.readArrayList(null)
parcel.writeList(transactionImages)
```

The error for parcel.readArrayList(null) :
Type mismatch. Required:ArrayList<String>? Found(ArrayList<Any!>?..ArrayList<*>?)

The error for parcel.writeList(transactionImages) :
Java type mismatch expected (Mutable)List<(raw) Any?>! but found ArrayList<String>?. Use explicit cast

Comment: Maybe this help. There are kotlin based answers also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201311/how-to-read-write-a-boolean-when-implementing-the-parcelable-interface?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using **Java** instead of **Kotlin** but I think this problem can handled by a same solution.

I often use:

- **parcel.createStringArrayList()** instead of **parcel.readArrayList(null)**
- **parcel.writeStringList(transactionImages)** instead of ***parcel.writeList(transactionImages)***

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for OOT, but you can use `@Parcelize` to create a `Parcelable` class:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class CustomerTxn(

    @field:SerializedName("txn_note")
    val txnNote: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("txn_date")
    val txnDate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("amount")
    val amount: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("txn_type")
    val txnType: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("contact")
    val contact: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("transaction_images")
    var transactionImages: ArrayList<String>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("created_at")
    val createdAt: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("cashbook")
    val cashbook: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("view_type")
    val viewType: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("modified_at")
    val modifiedAt: String? = null
): Parcelable
```

So don't have to worry about saving `ArrayList<String>` into parcel.