# Array List of objects via intent

Tags: java, android

I know you can pass in an array list of String via intent, but what if it's an array list of some object that I defined? Say an array list of Bicyles, how do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make your objects implement Parcelable and use `putParcelableArrayListExtra`. Alternatively, you can serialize your objects in some way and put the byte array of your serialized objects. However, while `Serializable` is easier to implement, it does not perform as well at run time--requiring all objects to be converted to byte streams and generating lots of temporary objects.

There are a lot of examples of how to implement `Parcelable`, including several in this thread. If you're using Kotlin, the easiest is to use the `kotlin-parcelize` plugin. First, add the following to your module's build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then, make your `Bicycle` class parcelable:

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class Bicycle(val id: Int, val brand: String): Parcelable
```

Now you can pass an array list of `Bicycle` via an intent using `putParcelableArrayListExtra`:

```
var bicycles : MutableList<Bicycle> = ...

...

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("bicycles",
    bicycles as java.util.ArrayList<out Parcelable>
)
```

The receiving activity can retrieve the bicycles like this:

```
var bicycles : List<Bicycle>

list=intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bicycles")
```

If you're targeting API level 33 or later, you can use:

```
list=intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("bicycles", Bicycle)
```

which has better type safety.

Comment: @adit - For a code example of making something Parcelable, look at the [docs for Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Then you can use an ArrayList<MyParcelableClass> in a call to `putParcelableArrayListExtra()`.

Comment: having issues as my object has a Location object, so don't really know on how to handle this in the writeToParcel method

Comment: @adit - Location implements Parcelable itself, so in your writeToParcel method, you can just use Parcel's `writeParcelable` to write the Location along with the rest of your data.

Comment: please put examples not suggestions

Comment: This is not a solution! This is just a regular, completely unusefull, "bla-bla-bla" answer. The only solution is: wannik's answer!

Comment: @Vitaly - What an odd comment. The main difference in our answers is that wannik offered code you can copy and paste (perhaps without understanding what it's doing). Using `Parcelable` is better than using `Serializable` for a number of reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, you are right - main difference is you didn't provide code - you just say: "we need to-do something..."- this is bad and not informative for other users. Another main difference is that wannik provided the solution - you are not. On more main differencee is that you provided wronge solution - wannik is provided the right working one. We don't need implement Parcelable interface, for transfering array list of objects to intent - we can use just standard ArrayList class - nothing more! You can see it in wannik's solution.
All above is just my opnion. You can have another one.

Comment: @Vitaly - Sorry, but using `Serializable` is an inferior solution in all respects except for ease of coding. `Parcelable` results in faster code. It doesn't require objects to be converted to bytes. `Serializable` results in lots of temporary objects and triggers more garbage collection than `Parcelable`. (You have a good point about my answer lacking sample code. I've fixed that.)

Answer (score 24):

This is an example. `MainActivity` sends list of persons to `OtherActivity` via `Intent`.

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String name;

    Person(int i, String s) {
        id = i;
        name = s;
    }
}

public class TestAndroidActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        list.add(new Person(1, "Tom"));
        list.add(new Person(5, "John"));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActitity.class);
        intent.putExtra("list", list);
        startActivity(intent);
```

OtherActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OtherActitity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        ArrayList<Person> list = (ArrayList<Person>) i
                .getSerializableExtra("list");
        Toast.makeText(this, list.get(1).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using *Serializable* for this involves a performance penalty, so you actually should use *Parcelable*.

Comment: `intent.putExtra("list", list);` gives me an error : `cannot resolve method`

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped me solve the problem. I have one question. When I create a `List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();` object, it gave me error. But Creating a `ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();` object didn't give any error. What is the difference.

Comment: @viper Maybe you forgot to import java.util.List;

Comment: Note that you **MUST** pass an **ArrayList** and not a **List** otherwise it will show an error: `Cannot resolve method putExtra`

Answer (score 9):

One more way  - you can serialize list of objects into some kind of string representation (let it be JSON) and then retrieve the string value back to list

```
// here we use GSON to serialize mMyObjectList and pass it throught intent to second Activity
String listSerializedToJson = new Gson().toJson(mMyObjectList);
intent.putExtra("LIST_OF_OBJECTS", listSerializedToJson);
startActivity(intent);

// in second Activity we get intent and retrieve the string value (listSerializedToJson) back to list 
String listSerializedToJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("LIST_OF_OBJECTS");
mMyObjectList = new Gson().fromJson(objectsInJson, MyObject[].class); // in this example we have array but you can easy convert it to list - new ArrayList<MyObject>(Arrays.asList(mMyObjectList));
```

Answer (score 7):

A better idea is to implement Parcelable interface for the object whose arraylist you want to put in the Intent .For Example :

```
public class Person implements Parcelable{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return this.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
    }
}
```

And then application code you can say :

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("personList", personList);
```

Comment: That's what the first answer says.