# ArrayList to ProximityAlert methode onReceive - fatal error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast

I'm trying to receive array in proximity alert. The only thing I could send is one Long. This is how I set proximity alert:

```
private void setProximityAlert(double lat, double lon, final long eventID, int requestCode)
{
    float radius = 30f;
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(ProximityAlert.EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, eventID);
    intent.putExtra("pole", mPositions);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, -1, pendingIntent);
}
```

It doesn't crash when i comment "intent.putExtra("pole", mPositions);".

This is the array:

> `private ArrayList<LatLonPair> mPositions;`

And this is receiver:

```
public class ProximityAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA = "EventIDIntentExtraKey";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long eventID = intent.getLongExtra(EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, -1);
    ArrayList<LatLonPair> list = (ArrayList<LatLonPair>) intent.getSerializableExtra("list");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Event: " + eventID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Without the one putExtra it's working, but i need that array. So this is not working for me: 
[Array List of objects via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109867/array-list-of-objects-via-intent)

LogCat error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts/co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.ProximityDisplay}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.models.LatLonPair@44fb61f0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.models.LatLonPair@44fb61f0
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1116)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:510)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1076)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:479)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:493)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5438)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:2206)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:230)
    at co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.ProximityDisplay.setProximityAlert(ProximityDisplay.java:91)
    at co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.ProximityDisplay.registerIntents(ProximityDisplay.java:79)
    at co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.ProximityDisplay.onCreate(ProximityDisplay.java:43)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    ... 11 more
```

This is LatLonPair Class:

```
package co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class LatLonPair implements Parcelable{
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;
private String popis;
private String nadpis;

public LatLonPair() {
    mLatitude = -2.60312596534349;
    mLongitude = 51.4558140934651;
    popis = "Nezadany popis";
    nadpis = "Nezadany nadpis";
}

public LatLonPair(double latitude, double longitude, String popis, String nadpis) {
    mLatitude = latitude;
    mLongitude = longitude;
    this.popis = popis;
    this.nadpis = nadpis;
}

public static boolean isValid(double lat, double lon) {

    if((lon >= -180 && lon <= 180) && (lat >= -90 && lat <= 90)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public String getPopis() {
    return popis;
}

public String getNadpis() {
    return nadpis;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    mLatitude = latitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return mLatitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    mLongitude = longitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return mLongitude;
}

public GeoPoint getGeoPoint() {
    return new GeoPoint((int) (mLatitude * 1E6), (int) (mLongitude * 1E6));
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Please always post stack traces with crashes.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes of course, I'm sorry... Now it's edidted (I hope LogCat is enough)

Comment: @MartinPolak it can't fully marshal `LatLonPair`, maybe you're not implementing it properly or have something that can't be marshalled?

Comment: LogCat is perfect.  What A--C said, can you post your LatLon pair definition (the class definition and all of its member variables are what we need to see

Comment: @A--C sorry I'm new on this... What does it mean it can't be marshalled? What could be wrong with LetLonPair? What class cannot have  to be marshalled?

Comment: @MartinPolak When you `marshal/serialize` a class you write its data members to disk. You basically "save" the class. Then you can reconstruct the class somewhere else since you have it stored. This is the approach for Objects passed via `Intent`s. Since this is your own class, having the code can tell us what is wrong.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html You don't actually write to the parcel, nor do you have a `CREATOR`

Comment: @A--C Thank you. Now i pasted whole class LatLonPair. With "implements Parceable" it wont crash on start, but when that intent happens. Now it's just `Error receiving broadcast Intent 
 { act=co.uk.gauntface.android.proximityalerts.action.PROXIMITY_ALERT (has extras)`

Comment: @MartinPolak Not sure about that, does the stack trace say more?

Comment: @A--C I implemented CREATOR and now it's not crashing :) Thank you :) But now I have problem that it's like... empty or I dont't know what... I have to test it... But thank you very much :)

Comment: @A--C If I could ask one more question... when I try to get size, it's okay and say 4 items... But when I want string in "onReceive", it returns just default value from LatLonPair - "Nezadany popis" and not what's in there. When i try the same code from the same array (but from main) `mPositions.get(0).getNadpis()` it's ok... I have no idea why it's doing that :-(

Comment: Unfortunately neither do I at the moment. Keep trying and if you get stumped, make another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `super(dest,flags)` in the overridden `writeToParcel` method in `LatLonPair` class

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I didn't have `implements Parceable` and after that it didn't have `CREATE`. After that it wasn't crashing and the array lenght was OK, but items had default value. I guess problem was with bad implementation of saving variables in Parceable - it reseted itself. So I  gave up and send to broadcastreceiver just few strings I needed there. Thank you all for help.