# How do you pass a Jsoup Elements object between activities?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which logs into my school gradebook, retrieves grades, and stores them in an Elements object. However, I now need to pass this object to another activity which will wire the grades into a `recyclerview`, and I don't know how to accomplish this. I tried doing something like this, but I don't know how to extract the `Elements` in the second activity. I am aware that there is another similar question but there was no clear solution for it.

```
Intent GradeList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GradeList.class);
        GradeList.putExtra("grades",w.gradeList);
        startActivity(GradeList);
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have to pass Elements object? Why not make own object that implements Serializable / Parceable, throw it into arraylist and pass that?

Comment: @poss I have been trying to do something like that, can you elaborate a little as to the process? Im a little unsure...

Comment: It would help a lot to know structure of your application to know what are you getting from Elements. For example, is it necessary to have getting data from internet and recyclerview separated in different activities? But generally this is what you can do - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109867/array-list-of-objects-via-intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to serialize your `Elements` object into a Json string, put it into your intent via `Intent.putExtra(key, jsonString)` then deserialize it back to an `Elements` object in the target `Activity`.

The code would be something like:

```java
// I suppose w.GradeList returns an Elements object.
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(w.GradeList, Elements.class);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GradeList.class);
intent.putExtra(SOME_PUBLIC_STATIC_KEY, json);

// On the target Activity.
Intent intent = getIntent();
String json = intent.getStringExtra(SOME_PUBLIC_STATIC_KEY);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Elements elements = gson.fromJson(json, Elements.class);
```

Comment: when I do the initial String serial = gson.toJson(w.GradeList,Elements.class) i get a stackoverflow error

Comment: @steve Hi, I see that you accepted my answer. Have you solved the stack overflow issue?

Comment: well, I ended up converting my Elements object to an array list and passing it with an intent but your solution was useful for the future so