# way to put arraylist in putExtras

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send a ArrayList with intent for starting new activity.
I have something like this-

```
ArrayList<LatLng> positions = new ArrayList<LatLng>() ;
positions.add(new LatLng(12,13));
positions.add(new LatLng(13,14));
positions.add(new LatLng(14,15));
Intent intent = new Intent(Current.this,Next.class);
```

Now I want to carry this ArrayList named positions to the Next activity and want to use there. How can I achieve it.

Comment: putParcelableArrayListExtra(name, value)

Comment: possible duplicate [Array List of objects via intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109867/array-list-of-objects-via-intent)

Answer (score 0):

**[LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng)** class already implements **Parcelable** So you can directly pass this arraylist as

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
intent.putExtra("array",positions.toArray());
```

Comment: That puts an array, not an Arraylist