# What's different of putSerializable and putParcelable in Java?

Tags: java, android, bundle

Hi I'm beginner developer of Android :) I want to send `ArrayList<Custom>` value from `Activity` to `Fragment`. I know that have to use `Bundle`, but I don't know what's method can help me.

1. What is different of `putSerializable` and `putParcelable`?
2. In my situation, Which method can help me `putParcelableArrayList` or `putSerializable`?

Thanks all that give me opportunity to grow :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

Comment: @IvoBeckers Oh.. Why I can't found that's question T-T Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Serializable` and `Parcelable` are both an interface. The former is as ancient as java. It allows you to store/write an object in a persistent way. The beauty of it is that you just have to implement the interface. The latter, `Parcelable`, is android specific. It is faster than `Serializable`, but you will have to implement the method of the interface to be able to use it.

> What is different of putSerializable and putParcelable

`putSerializable` accepts objects that implement `Serializable`, putParcelable accepts objects that implement `Parcelable`

> In my situation, Which method can help me putParcelableArrayList or
>   putSerializable?

It is difficult to say. Generally speaking I would say `Parcelable`

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, `Parcelable` are way more faster than `Serializable`. Here is a great article if yout want to learn more about it http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between putSerializable and putParcelable other than the actual value added to the map for the given key. Same goes for  putParcelableArrayList. At the given key you will read a  `SparseArray<? extends Parcelable>` .

Blackbelt explained it pretty well.

From my point of view, you don't need to use Serializable internally.
I recommend using android's container for messages (a Parceable). You never know where Android SDK will go, and you do want to ensure max compatibility with ease. Remember, Android has it's own SDK (not Java's).

Answer (score 1):

For both you had to implements `Parcelable` or `Serializable` class, both allow persistence.

`Parcelable` is faster and you will write more function to make it work:

`describeContents()
 writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
 Parcelable.Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyClass>()
 MyClass(Parcel in) //an constructor for Parcel object (Parcelable)`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

`Serializable` is lower but you only had to add the interface on the class to make it work:

`private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;` should be set inside the class that implements Serializable
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 1):

[Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) in android is an interface and every object that wants to be passed across different activities using intent has to implement this interface.This interface has two method that we have to **`implements: describeContent()`** that returns an int and `writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)` that returns a void. More over a class that implements this interface must have a static field called `CREATOR` that is used by the OS to recreate the object.Clearly Parcelable array can be pass via Intent in android. This is the most elegant way to pass data between activities and exploit all the android power.

[Serialization](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) is usually used When the need arises to send your data over network or stored in files.