# Confused about the inner workings of Serializable

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a class `Den` implementing the `Serializable` interface:

```
public class Den implements Serializable {

    private double id;
    private String name;

    public Den(double id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I can send a `Den` instance in an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("OBJECT_KEY", new Den(20.2, "JOHN"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And receive it in another `Activity` like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Den den = (Den) intent.getSerializableExtra("OBJECT_KEY");
```

Now my question is: Why do I need to implement the `Serializable` interface on `Den`, but not on primitive data types like `int`, `float` or `String`? What is happening internally?

Comment: Because you can't, which in turn is because they are already defined. All primitives are already serializable, and so is `String`, as you can see from the Javadoc. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I need to implement the Serializable interface on Den, but not
>   on primitive data types like int, float or String?

String is a Serializable and no primitive type.

Primitive types cannot implement interfaces.

The JVM takes care of fields with a primitive type when serializing an object.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types are already Serializable

In your own types, consider implement the  [Parcelable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) better than Serializable

There are some plugins for Android Studio that make it very easy to implement and the result is a better performance

Answer (score 0):

The `Intent` class already gives you the capability to pass a variety of data types (most of which are primitive) between activities via `putExtra()`. So you'd only need to implement `Serializable` on custom objects.

Also like Alberto suggested, it's better practice to implement `Parcelable` because it's specific to the android platform and likely more optimized. Check this for more info between the two, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)