# Serializable and Parcelable in Android

Tags: android

I am not clear about distinct use of interface `Serializable` and `Parcelable` in Android. If we prefer the use of `Parcelable`, then why we do so over `Serializable`. Moreover, if I pass data through any webservice, can `Parcelable` help? If so, then how?

Comment: Possibly duplicate check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Answer (score 2):

So the main difference is the speed, and it matters on your hand-held device.  Supposedly less powerful than your desktop.

With `Serialisable` which comes for goold old Java, your code will look like this:

```
class MyPojo implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

No extra methods are needed as `reflection` will be used to get all fields and their values.  And this can me slow or is slower than ...

and to use `Parcelable` you have to write something like this:

```
class MyPojo implements Parcelable {
    String name;
    int age;

    MyPojo(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        age = in.readInt();
    }

    void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(age);
    }

    int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // and here goes CREATOR as well and what not
};
```

according to guys @google it can be much much faster, `Parcelable`s that is.

Of course, there are tools to help you with adding all necessary fields to make a class `Parcelable` like https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler