# How to pass ArrayList<File> object from one Activity to another Activity using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have a ArrayList documents and I want to send this file to another Activity. but How to get This value in SecondActivity

What I tried is 
In First Activity

```
 private ArrayList<File> documents;
Intent selectLabInt = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

 selectLabInt.putExtra("patient_name", patientNameStr);
 selectLabInt.putExtra("referal_notes", referalNotesStr);
 selectLabInt.putExtra("fileList",documents);

 startActivity(selectLabInt);
```

Comment: What is data type of patient_name,referal_notes,fileList?

Comment: Those are String type

Comment: @SabyaSachi Is the `File` class same as `java.io.File`?

Comment: So you want to pass string type of data or object of ArrayList i.e. document?

Comment: Use this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35741541/1770868

Comment: I want to pass ArrayList<File> object to sec Activity

Comment: Refer following link and let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `File` is serializable,then you can pass the `ArrayList` like this:

In the sending Activity:

```
ArrayList<File> documents= new ArrayList<File>();
intent.putExtra("documents", documents);
```

In the receiving Activity:

```
ArrayList<File> documents = (ArrayList<File>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("documents");
```

Comment: File class implements Serializable internally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make File class **parcelable** so that you can pass arraylist of that class in intent via **[putParcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable))**.

here is example of same https://stackoverflow.com/a/6681784/942224

Comment: File class implements Serializable internally.

Comment: yeah  than you need to follow jas's answer