# How to pass a single ArrayList<CustomObj> elements to another Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

You've got an ArrayList for example:

```
list = new ArrayList<Obj>();
list.add(new Obj(R.drawable.img, "string", "na, na, na"));
list.add(new Obj(R.drawable.ima2, "string 2", "Na, na, na"));
list.add(new Obj(R.drawable.img3, "string 3", "Na, na, na"));
...
```

this List inflates into a `RecyclerView`.

When I click a `RecyclerView` Item, I want to pass only the element of the list I have clicked on to another Activity, not the whole List.

**How do I do it?**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ChordsListActivity.this, ChordActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selected", list);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK please, have a look at the question

Comment: What is `chords`? Make a new list and add to it the selected items.

Comment: @vucko I misstyped now it is correct

Comment: Ok, I still see no problem with this. Just create a new empty list and add a new item to it when it's selected, and remove it once it's deselected. Eventually just pass that new list in the way described in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to pass a single ArrayList elements to another Activity

For passing custom object to next Activity do following:

**1.** Make sure custom object class implementing `Serializable` or `Parcelable`([recommended to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)) interface.

**2.** Use `Bundle.putSerializable` if implementing `Serializable` or use `Bundle.putParcelable` if implementing `Parcelable` interface.

Using Serializable:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("selected", chords.get(position));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**3.** In next Activity use `Bundle. getSerializable` for getting selected object:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Obj selectedObj=(Obj)bundle.getSerializable("selected");
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `Parcelable` in Android, because `Serializable` takes care of a lot of additional stuff, which you don't need (e.g. Serializable is
designed for durable storage of objects, where the file might be read back in months
or years later). Parcelable is faster than Serializable for
Android’s IPC use.

Comment: Thank you! Right now I'm using Serializable but I'm gonna change to Parcelable!

Comment: @Vucko: Agree with you.

Comment: In point 3 if I want to use Parcelable, instead of `bundle.getSerializable()` I imagine I have to use `bundle.getParcelable()` right?

Comment: @Daniele:  Yes right , but you also need to use `putParcelable ` instead of `putSerializable ` in `ChordsListActivity ` Activity

Comment: Yes, It makes sense! Thank you very much for the detailed answer

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK please make sure that on point 2. you have `intent.putExtras(bundle)` instead of `intent.putExtra(bundle)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ChordsListActivity.this, ChordActivity.class);
            // ListData is supposed to be the list which pass to your adapter

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("itemData", list.get(position));
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);       
        }
    });
```

**Retrive it:**

```
 Obj challenge = this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("itemData");
```

Comment: You are putting an individual item as an Arraylist? Right idea, wrong code

Comment: Thanks, but you updated the wrong line. The put is wrong and now the get is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Obj` class a `Parcelable` like this

```
private static class Obj implements Parcelable {
    private int img;
    private String string;
    private String naNaNa;

    public Obj(@DrawableRes int img, String string, String naNaNa) {
        this.img = img;
        this.string = string;
        this.naNaNa = naNaNa;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.img);
        dest.writeString(this.string);
        dest.writeString(this.naNaNa);
    }

    protected Obj(Parcel in) {
        this.img = in.readInt();
        this.string = in.readString();
        this.naNaNa = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Obj> CREATOR = new Creator<Obj>() {
        @Override
        public Obj createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Obj(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Obj[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Obj[size];
        }
    };
}
```

then put it into extra of intent