# Android : Single Fragment Swipe on ViewPager to load next or previous record

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ListView which contains product details. On Item click of listview I open new activity with particular product detail. I wanted to convert activity to ViewPager so that I can swipe to load next and previous records in same fragment. Fragment structure will be same for all records. I don't know from where should I start. Can you give me overview idea how to achieve this. Here is my model class.

> Product.java

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

    public int id;
    public String Name;
    public String description;
    public String longDescription;
    public String amount;
    public String image;
}
```

Here is my FragmentPagerAdapter class

> ProductPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ProductPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Product> list;

    public ProductPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, ArrayList<Product> list) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ProductFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my Fragment

> ProductFragment.java

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {

    public ProductFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

        //findViewById...

        return v;
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance(int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("Id", id);
        ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

And now on list item Click I am opening new activity. And I am sending Product object to it.

```
lv_itemRateList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                Product r = new Product();
                r = rateListArrayList.get(i);
                intent.putExtra("product",r);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

My DetailsActivity contains my viewpager. Now can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-) Need a custom adapter for ViewPager.

I assumed that all the pages will have the same content, so all of them have the same layout so ProductPagerAdapter extends the [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).

```
public class ProductPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
     //variables
     private Context context;
     private ArrayList<Product> list;
     private Product product

     //views
    TextView  txtName ;

    public ProductPagerAdapter(Context context, List<Product> list) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return  list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == ( object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
        product = list.get(position);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container,false);

        txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText(product.Name)

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object); 
    }
}
```

2-) Adapter is ready. Now let's prepare the activity that will show the details. First initialize ViewPager and ProductPagerAdapter. Then show the details of the item which is selected by clicking on the previous activity.

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity
{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ...

            //getting product object
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Product product = (Product) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("product");

            //get selected item id
            int selectedItemID = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) 
            {
               if(list.get(i).id == product.id)
               {
                selectedItemID = i;
                break;
               }
            }

            //Init ViewPager and adapter
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            ProductPagerAdapter detailAdapter = new ProductPagerAdapter(DetailActivity.this, list);

            // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
            viewPager.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedItemID); // set selection
            viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ForegroundToBackgroundTransformer()); //custom transformer

            ...
        }
}
```

3-) We've done what we have to do so far. So it will work like this. But what I would like to point out is that there are a few things to make the ViewPager better.

**Performance** :  Use [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) instead of [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). Parcelable takes more time to implement but it will perform 10 times faster and use less resources. Please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647471/5392118)

**Animation** : You may want to need animations for transforming ViewPager. I suggest you to use [ViewPagerTransforms](https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms)

**Indicators** : If you want to use the paging indicator, I recommend [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator).

For more on [ViewPager](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111)

Comment: how can I get reference of list in activity. I am getting compile time error.

Comment: it's just an arraylist in which there are Product objects like List<Product> list = new ArrayList();

Comment: if I write `List<Product> list = new ArrayList();` this then list will be empty. How can I get same data as previous activity list.

Comment: First, convert this list to JSON string by using GSON. Then add the converted string as an extra to intent in the ListView's click. In DetailsActivity, get that string from intent and convert it to list by using GSON.