# Passing an ArrayList<Object> from one Intent to another

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList in ActivityA and i want to pass it to ActivityB.

ActivityA:

```
ArrayList<CardDetails> cardDetailsToPass = new ArrayList<>();

        if (v.getId() == balance.getId()){
            for(CardDetails cardDetails : cardDetailsArrayList){
                int clientID = cardDetails.getClientID();
                int cardID = cardDetails.getCardID();
                int cardNo = cardDetails.getCardNo();
                int balance = cardDetails.getCardBalance();
                int availableBalance = cardDetails.getCardAvailableBalance();
                int limit = cardDetails.getCardLimit();
                int expDate = cardDetails.getExpDate();
                String status = cardDetails.getStatus();

                cardDetailsToPass.add(new CardDetails(clientID,cardID,cardNo,balance,availableBalance,limit,expDate,status));

                Log.d("Adapter","clientID               "+cardDetails.getClientID());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardID                 "+cardDetails.getCardID());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardNo                 "+cardDetails.getCardNo());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardBalance            "+cardDetails.getCardBalance());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardAvailableBalance   "+cardDetails.getCardAvailableBalance());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardLimit              "+cardDetails.getCardLimit());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardExpDate            "+cardDetails.getExpDate());
                Log.d("Adapter","cardStatus             "+cardDetails.getStatus());

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CardStatementActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cardDetailsToPass",cardDetailsToPass);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

ActivityB:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_statement);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
       //get the ArrayList here
    }
}
```

I've tried one method of doing this but with no success. Does passing an ArrayList of Objects require something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the arraylist of your custom define object  either by using serializable or parcelable.

use the below link that helps lot

[Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a list of plain Java objects to an `Intent`.

What you *can* do is `CardDetails` class implement `Parcelable` and use the method [putParcelableArrayListExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))

Answer (score 0):

You try the below, you `CardDetails` must `implement Parceable`

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", ArrayList<T extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve it

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```