# How to put the ArrayList into bundle

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have put some value into arraylist like this :

```
    private List<InfoProduct> product;

    product = new ArrayList<>();
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "0", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.guitar, Product_title, "1", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "2", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.guitar, Product_title, "3", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "4", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.guitar, Product_title, "5", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "6", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.guitar, Product_title, "7", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "8", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
    product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.guitar, Product_title, "9", Product_data2, lunch,R.drawable.cardview_circle_corner));
```

when I need to go other Fragment , I want to use Bundle to transfer my ArrayList , so I write some code to comply this

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_youtube, new FragmentYoutubeProduct(), "youtube");
    ft.addToBackStack("youtube");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList("Product",product);
    ft.commit();
```

I got error on `bundle.putStringArrayList("Product",product);` , how can I do to resolve this question ?

Comment: Its your custom class so you need to pass as a seriliazable or parcable

Comment: do not put `List<InfoProduct>` when method expects to get `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) note: its about putting Extras which is in fact Bundle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make `InfoProduct` Parcelable
Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable)

Then use

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(product)
```

You can get `ArrayList` by

```
getParcelableArrayList(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `bundle.putParcelableArrayList()` and instantiate your list as private `ArrayList<InfoProduct> product;`.Also make sure that InfoProduct is Parcelable.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the arraylist of your custom define object either by implementing `serializable` or `parcelable`.

[Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

Answer (score 1):

Your code of

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("Product",product);
```

Is trying to place an array list of strings into the bundle.  However, you don't have an array list of strings.  You have an array list of `InfoProduct`

Therefore you need to put your array list of  into the bundle.  For this you need to use [the method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) `putParcelableArrayList`

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Product", product);
```

In order to do this you also need to ensure that your object `InfoProduct` in parcelable, which is serializable by Android.  So you need to have it implement the [Parcelable interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable) might also help you with that.