# Convert List<?> to List<String> in Android

Tags: java, android

```
public List<Contact> getContacts()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String cmd;
    List<Contact> name = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contact;" , null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int contactID       = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        String familyName   = cursor.getString(1);
        String firstName    = cursor.getString(2);
        int houseNumber     = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
        String street       = cursor.getString(4);
        String town         = cursor.getString(5);
        String country      = cursor.getString(6);
        String postcode     = cursor.getString(7);
        int telephoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8));
        Contact contact     = new Contact(contactID,familyName,firstName,houseNumber,street,town,country,postcode,telephoneNumber);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Database.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contacts", name);
    startActivity(intent);

    return name;
}
```

The method `putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>)` in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments `(String, List<Contact>)`

in order to use `putStringArrayListExtra();` method, i need to convert `List<contact>` name to List name, How do i convert it?
thank you

Comment: The thing is, you need everything in your `ArrayList` to be a `String`, which in this case it is clearly not.  Ultimately, the answer to your question depends on what you want the `String` for each `Contact` to look like.

Comment: Maybe better to use Serializable? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Comment: @JoeC, I mean you can create your own class wrapping List<Contact> implementing Serializable and use it.

Comment: why would you want to pass the entire list when the target activity could simply read it from your sqlite db?

Answer (score 1):

because list of object is actually not a list of strings, the best way as i know is to loop over list and convert each item into a new list of strings :

```
List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for (Object object : list) {
    stringsList.add(Objects.toString(object, null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Declare a new Array Of Strings.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(list.size());
newList.addAll(list);
```

This adds all elements into the new String List. Where list is your previous container.

Also to pass objects between components use Parceble, Android uses Binder to facilitate such communication in a highly optimized way. The Binder communicates with Parcels, which is a message container. The Binder marshals the Parcel to be sent, sends and receives it, and then unmarshals it on the other side to reconstruct a copy of the original Parcel.Please read up on it [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to pass your `List<Contacts>` to via `Intent` -

No need to use `putStringArrayListExtra()` methods as there is `putParcelableArrayList()` method using which you can pass `ArrayList<Contact>` directly.

Simply use,

```
putParcelableArrayList("KEY", your ArrayList<Contact>); // Make sure Contact implementes Parcelable
```

You can get the `ArrayList<Contact>` in Receiver `Activity` -

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Contact> data = b.getParcelableArrayList("KEY");
```

However, You can use `Serializable` instead of `Parcelable` but `Parcelable` is recommended as it is like Flash. Here is [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

Comment: Serializable is not recommended on android, Therefore i am certain you meant Parceble?

Comment: Yeah, use `Parcelable`. This is why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable