# How to put latlong object in parcelable class

Tags: android, badparcelableexception

I want to send class Object to another activity which contains Latlng. But it gives exception. Below is my class which has latlng field.

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Keep;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Institute implements Serializable,Parcelable {

private String instituteName;
private LatLng latLng;

 protected Institute(Parcel in) {
    instituteName = in.readString();
   latLng = in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader());

}

    public static final Creator<Institute> CREATOR = new Creator<Institute>() {
    @Override
    public Institute createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Institute(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Institute[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Institute[size];
    }
};


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

    parcel.writeString(instituteName);
   parcel.writeParcelable(latLng,PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE);

}

  public String getInstituteName() {
    return instituteName;
}

public void setInstituteName(String instituteName) {
    this.instituteName = instituteName;
}

    public void setLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
    this.latLng = latLng;
}

    public LatLng getLatLng() {
    return latLng;
}


}
```

And it gives me following exception

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: in.thoughtsmith.jink, PID: 24906
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.thoughtsmith.jink/in.thoughtsmith.jink.InstituteDetails}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: Seed0004
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: Seed0004
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
    at in.thoughtsmith.jink.Institute.<init>(Institute.java:45)
    at in.thoughtsmith.jink.Institute$1.createFromParcel(Institute.java:55)
    at in.thoughtsmith.jink.Institute$1.createFromParcel(Institute.java:52)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2367)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:786)
    at in.thoughtsmith.jink.InstituteDetails.onCreate(InstituteDetails.kt:34)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please help me how can i send class which contains latlng to another activity. And also please let me know is there any better way to achieve same

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract your latitude and longitude from latLng

```
double lat = latlng.latitude;
double lng = latlng.longitude;
```

Then you can add it easely to your Parcelable

Comment: No. LatLng implements Parcelable which can be sent and read as parcelable

Comment: How do you know what LatLng class are we talking here about?

Comment: Its a Google-Class: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Comment: Instead of passing Latlng Object to Institute he can pass directly the two double

Comment: Why should he want to pass two doubles instead of using parcelable since the LatLng class implements it?

Comment: Brother's i know i can pass two double and implement serializable. I was trying to do this with parcelable and it gave me exception.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is that you implement Serializable and Parcelable.

Serializable is used to serialize data (non android way which is slower). Since LatLng implements parcelable you should only use Parcelable. Parcelable is like Serializeable but a faster way serializing simple datas. Serializable doesnt know how to use [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng).

Make sure that you use the proper import since LatLng may be used in a different package aswell.

You should also use the flags used by the writeToParc method. Means:

```
@Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(instituteName);
    parcel.writeParcelable(this.latLng, flags);
}

protected Institute(Parcel in) {
     this.instituteName = in.readString();
     this.latLng = in.readParcelable(LatLng.class.getClassLoader());
}
public class Institute implements Parcelable {}
```

Difference between Serializable and Parcelable: [Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

Comment: Check my edit. just tried it in a sample project. Please edit your Question with the imports you have used.

Comment: I think it should be `dest` not `parcel'` at `parcel.writeString(instituteName);` and `parcel.writeParcelable(this.latLng, flags);`