# start activity from ListView and then next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

So I have a ListView of exercises, when I click an item i go to Detail.java activity and I display the informations of the exercise, but I have a button next in the bottom to go to the next exercise.i don't have any idea to do that without creating many activities of Detail.

Comment: Wat about fragments instead of activity use fragments to replace content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand from the info u gave:
You can pass object between activities using Serializable and Parcelable Interface that your object should implement

[Using Serializable and Parcelable instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

> The next step passing data from your main activity to the detailed activity

**Using serializable**

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> yourModelList= new ArrayList<Model>();
intent.putExtra("modelList", yourModelList);
```

> Retrieve data

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> modelList= (ArrayList<ModelClass>).getIntent().getSerializableExtra("modelList");
```

**Using parcelable**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Detail.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("modelList", modelList);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Retrieve Data in your Detail.java activity

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> modelList= getIntent().getParcelableArrayList("modelList");
```

**Besides I highly recommend you using Fragment, coz it gets messy once you start iterating through your arraylist from one activity to another saving ID's and other stuff**
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: thank you it works, but getParcelableExtra("modelList") doesn't work i used getStringArrayListExtra..

Comment: I have edited my answer try using .putParcelableArrayListExtra and getParcelableArrayListExtra

Answer (score 0):

You can start Detail activity with a bundle with the parameters you want, in this example the id of the next exercise.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Detail.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putInt("id", theIdOfNextExercise);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Then, in the launched Detail activity, you can read the parameter via:

```
int exerciseId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id", 0);
```

And then show the detail related to that exercise in your Detail Activity.
I've set the default value as 0, so if exerciseId > 0 you have the id of the exercise to show.

> Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all primitive types, Serializables and Parcelables. The use of an integer with putInt/getInt is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bundle to save the id of your exercise and than catch it to the activity you called... i suggest you to use fragment, it's more difficult but it's smartest and more user friendly