# Send Data from activity to service directly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

Anyone know about how to fix my code?
in my StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener there is putExtra which is will send the data to ActivityShow.class

```
StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,ActivityShow.class);
        // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
        intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", IdList.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

//send data to service
Intent serviceIntent = new 
Intent(Activity.this,ActivityService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("ListViewValue",  IdList.get(position));
startService(serviceIntent);
```

my problem is when I Try to add that putExtra directly to my service class, it give me an error that said IdList.get(position) red color for position,

I try to remove the get.(position) but it give me a null one, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: variable position cannot defined since it only define in `onItemClick`

Comment: so, can i change the onItemClick? to add that function to send my data not on itemclick, but directly when the app is open

Comment: But how does the app know which item is clicked ? There are something wrong with your logic. From the code you given, ListViewValue will store the  value based on the listview position you clicked. But now you want to get the data without listview click ?

Answer (score 0):

The position is a local variable which has scope up to the only onItemClick(). So either define another variable position outside the method and assign it a value in onItemClick().

Comment: But how does the app know which item is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `model` class that implements [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface. This way you would be able to *serialize* the object in your `Activity` and then *de-seialize* it back in your `Service` class.

A generic example for the same:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // Your activity code here

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    // onCreate() code
    // create and populate your list
    final ArrayAdapter<MyModel> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>();
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, pos, id) -> {
      MyModel model = myAdapter.get(pos);
      Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);
      intent.putExtra("ITEM", model);
      startService(intent); // basic threading rules apply! be carefull
    });
  }

  // inner class just for demo
  static class MyModel implements Parcelable {
    // your model goes here!

    public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      // write your model data into parcel
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyModel>() {
      public MyModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyModel(in);
      }

      public MyModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyModel[size];
      }
    };

    private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
      // create model from parcel
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `Service` you can get the model by

```
MyActivity.MyModel model = (MyActivity.MyModel) intent.getExtra("MODEL");
```

You can also use Java's Serialization but it is generally advised not to serialize Objects this way in Android. You can read more about it [on this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647471/6611700)

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable pos

then check you have clicked a item or not before sending value to service

```
int pos =-1;

StudentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
pos=position;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,ActivityShow.class);
        // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
        intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", IdList.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

//send data to service
if(pos>=0){
Intent serviceIntent = new 
Intent(Activity.this,ActivityService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("ListViewValue",  IdList.get(pos));

startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sound a little weird, but I found to fix this using shared preferences manager
thanks for your help