# Android - Kotlin Serializable vs Java Serializable , is the performance the same?

Tags: java, android, serialization, kotlin

I have read everywhere that Java Serializable is much slower than Parcelable . Is it the same case for Kotlin Serializable? Or is Kotlin Serializable equally fast as Kotlin Parcelable? Using Serializable seems to much simpler and i wanted to know if in Kotlin its fine to use Serializable instead of Parcelable.

Comment: Test and measure.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Native Kotlin Serialization, I quote from the official GitHub page, "is still highly experimental". So it's nothing like an alternative to the bog-standard Java Serialization or Android's native Parcelable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin standard library doesn't have its own definition of `Serializable`, if you have code using it you'll notice `import java.io.Serializable`. So it's exactly as fast.

There is `@Serializable` from [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) (thanks to Marko Topolnik for reminding me of it), but it works very differently and is not easier to use than `@Parcelize` (see below).

> Using Serializable seems to much simpler

But here you have an advantage: in Kotlin it's just as easy, just [use the `@Parcelize` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#enabling-parcelable-support) (see [the design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md) as well).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Serializable is exactly more simple than Parcelable but Parcelable is much more faster than Serializable. If your application not require maximize performance optimized, Serializable still fine.

Comment: In Kotlin, implementing Parcelable is much easier, so the trade-off changes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the same case for Kotlin Serializable? Or is Kotlin
>   Serializable equally fast as Kotlin Parcelable? Using Serializable
>   seems to much simpler and I wanted to know if in Kotlin its fine to
>   use Serializable instead of Parcelable.

Whether you are using `JAVA` or `Kotlin`, the internal working of `Serializable` and `Parcelable` will still remain same. Hence, even for Kotlin its recommend using Parcelable for better and faster performance.

Hope it helps.