# Performance / difference between passing via parcelable and native data structures?

Tags: java, android

New to android. More of a python contributor here on stack. So.

I am aware of how to pass native data via intent

i.e.:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PersonName", "Joe");
intent.putExtra("PersonId", "200");
startActivity(intent);
```

I am getting to the point where I have to pass more than just 2 attributes (say 3) between activities. This may be more tedious

I am also aware of Parcelable

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
Person person = new Person(); // class that implements parcelable
intent.putExtra("person", person);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am also aware that performance wise, Parcelable is superior to Serializing via this awesome thread
[Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My android app has a growing performance concern. (I have a long running socket service and also uploading / downloading images in the background at times) so would like to performance gains where I can. Is there a considerable performance difference here if any? Is it good practice to implement parcelable at a certain point, say if I'm passing 10 key-values as opposed to 3

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass basic data types directly to activities, so you aren't going to get anything non-negligible on the performance side.

> Is it good practice to implement parcelable at a certain

`Parcelable` should be used when groups of data are to be held together *logically* - think POJOs.

Comment: Thanks I think I do agree with that part in terms of passing and it makes sense but I was thinking that there also is some performance differences when it comes to serializing (probably bad wording because of Serializer sdk) response data into parcelable. For example I have a list of items(people) that i would have to serialize into parcelable

Comment: Note that you have a limit of 1 mb per transaction when passing data as parcelable, so if your list is big and you have a lot of data that needs to be passed i would go with primitive types

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic this case will likely not exceed 1mb but thank you! This is important to know.

Comment: @Dap do not worry about the performance of that. You see, those are convenience methods you're using to directly pass basic data (the `putExtra` ones). You may have noticed that in the `Activity` receiving them that they are actually packed into a `Bundle` for you. 
As for your growing performance problems, network requests will not only be executed in a background thread, but will be spending time based on internet speed and not system resources.

Comment: @NeelKamath thanks. I believe Ivan posted similar input. Do you have an opinion on the serialization of response data into parcelable?

Comment: Serialization has a performance toll regardless of whether you're using `Parcelable` or something else. However, Android takes care of the potential performance problems by using `Parcelable` and limiting the data you can transfer as Ivan said. As I stated earlier, unless logical, there's no need to serialise and since we're using Java/Kotlin, it's a simple language and hence not many decisions to make.