# Asking about Json serialization

Tags: android, serialization, okhttp

I know that when a class implements the `serializable` interface then the serialization on a java object will be done, this object will be become series of bytes. If an app communicates with a Webservice in `Json` format by using `OkHttp, Gson`. why does this app that has certain class have to implement the `serializable` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this wrong!

`OkHttp, Gson` does not need class to be serialized. But if you want to pass that model (Bean or Pojo what you say) to Bundle. Then you have to make it `Serializable`.

Like you have class A. And you want pass this to next activity.

```
 A model = new A();
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("modelA", model);
```

In `ReceiverActivity` onCreate() you write

```
 Model model = (Model) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("modelA");
```

If you don't extend `Serializable` to your class then you can not use this method even.

**By the way you should use Parcelable instead of Serializable. That will make your model class lengthy but its performance is better than Serializable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647471/6891563) for implementation.**