# Android Parcelable not transferring all the data when Custom Model had a child that is a list of type Custom Model

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a model ContentDto, which, among other variables, contains a list of type ContentDto. When I try to pass it to an activity using Parcelable, I get all the data except the child list of type ContentDto (which comes as null).

In my adapter:

```
val nextIntent = Intent(context, DynamicBaseActivity::class.java)
nextIntent.putExtra(Constants.DYNAMIC_DETAIL, contentDto)
context.startActivity(nextIntent)
```

In the receiving activity:

```
val bundle = intent.extras
if (bundle != null) {
    contentDto = bundle.getParcelable(Constants.DYNAMIC_DETAIL) as ContentDto
}
```

My ContentDto:

```
public class ContentDto implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("dataType")
    String dataType;
    @SerializedName("label")
    String label;
    @SerializedName("value")
    String value;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    String icon;
    @SerializedName("isMandatory")
    Boolean isMandatory;
    @SerializedName("isEditable")
    Boolean isEditable;
    @SerializedName("attributeValues")
    List<AttributeModel> attributeValues;
    @SerializedName("tableDto")
    TableDto tableDto;
    @SerializedName("contentDto")
    List<ContentDto> contentDto;    // This comes as null

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(dataType == null ? "" : dataType);
        dest.writeString(label == null ? "" : label);
        dest.writeString(value == null ? "" : value);
        dest.writeString(icon == null ? "" : icon);
        dest.writeInt((isMandatory == null ? 0 : isEditable ? 1 : 2));
        dest.writeInt((isEditable == null ? 0 : isMandatory ? 1 : 2));
        dest.writeParcelable(tableDto == null ? new TableDto() : tableDto, flags);
        dest.writeList(attributeValues == null ? new ArrayList<AttributeModel>(0) : attributeValues);
        dest.writeList(contentDto == null ? new ArrayList<ContentDto>(0) : contentDto);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ContentDto(Parcel in) {
        this();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public ContentDto() {
        super();
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        this.dataType = in.readString();
        this.label = in.readString();
        this.value = in.readString();
        this.icon = in.readString();
        switch (in.readInt()) {
            case 0:
                this.isMandatory = null;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.isMandatory = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.isMandatory = false;
                break;
        }
        switch (in.readInt()) {
            case 0:
                this.isEditable = null;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.isEditable = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.isEditable = false;
                break;
        }
        this.tableDto = in.readParcelable(TableDto.class.getClassLoader());
        in.readList(new ArrayList<AttributeModel>(), AttributeModel.class.getClassLoader());
        in.readList(new ArrayList<ContentDto>(), ContentDto.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContentDto> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContentDto>() {
        public ContentDto createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ContentDto(in);
        }

        public ContentDto[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContentDto[size];
        }
    };

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

(AttributeModel, TableDto and their children are also Parcelable)

Comment: make sure your custom list model also implemented parcelable

Comment: @VishalThakkar the custom list model is *same* as the parent type -> both are parcelable

Comment: @Kiya I am facing same problem. Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: @MangeshSambare ended up using `Serializable`

Comment: @Kiya Thanks for response, but `Serialzable` is slower as compared to `Parcelable`. Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647471/5015103

Comment: @MangeshSambare I am aware of that, which is why I was trying to use `Parcelable` in the first place...