# Passing arraylists between activities, Parcelable vs Serializable

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, kotlin

I'm trying to create an `Intent` with `ArrayList<Byte>` as extra.

So I have 3 options:

1. `putParceableArrayList(key: String?, value: ArrayList<out Parceable!>?)`
2. `putByteArray(key: String?, value: ByteArray?)`
3. `putSerializable(key: String?, value: Serializable?)`

I would prefer to not to use the 3rd option because Parceable objects are faster than Serializable ones ([Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)).

Discarding this option, I want to use the first option because I need this object as an ArrayList and not as a native array `bytes[]` (`ByteArray` on Kotlin).

The problem is that Byte object is native, so it does not implements Parceable. So that, I can't use the first option because it requires `ArrayList<out Parceable>`.

The best option I found is to transform the `ArrayList` to `ByteArray` and transform it back to an `ArrayList` when I unpack the extras like so:

```
intent.extras?.putByteArray(event, response.toByteArray())

[...]

var list = Arrays.asList(intent.extras?.getByteArray(event))
```

Which is the best option? Thank you!

Comment: I would use Serializable if you cannot avoid sending the whole list as an extra.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library, it makes your life simpler and you'll get rid of all the Parcelable interface boilerplate code