# How to use safe-args with MPP serializable data

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, kotlin-multiplatform, android-safe-args

I'm trying to use safe-args with kotlin-multiplatform types, however I keep geting the same issue during run-time when trying to pass serializable data:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models.MyModel is not Serializable or
>   Parcelable.

In my *nav_host.xml* I have the following:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/aFragment"
    android:name="com.corp.myapp.main.aFragment"
    android:label="aFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_aFragment_to_bFragment"
        app:destination="@id/bFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/bFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true">
        <argument
            android:name="myname"
            app:argType="org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models.MyModel"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </action>
</fragment>
```

Two approaches I'm using right now where i get the exact same exception.

First one is by using the *kotlinx-serialization* plugin where i have the following type:

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class MyModel(val first: String = "", val last: String = "")
```

Second one I tried by as first one didn't work was to make a platform specific (JVM) implementation with an extension of *java.io.Serializable* with the following:

*commondataModels.kt:*

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models

expect class MyModel(first: String, last: String)
```

*actualdataModels.kt:*

```
package org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models

import java.io.Serializable

actual data class MyModel actual constructor(val first: String, val last: String): Serializable
```

I'm making the navigation call in my Activity with the generated direction class:

```
import org.kotlin.mpp.mobile.models.*


val user = MyModel("Bruce","Lee")
host.findNavController().navigate(AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToBFragment(user))
```

**Thanks in advance for any advice!**

NOTE: I can make everything work by passing a Bundle with the [navigate API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20androidx.navigation.NavOptions,%20androidx.navigation.Navigator.Extras)), however I would like it to work with safe-args.

Comment: Perhaps use `@Parcelize`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thx for the tip but i'm sort of stuck with importing dependencies for it to work in my MPP module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CommonsWare suggested, use @Parcelize (and by extension, Parcelable)

[image]

The trick is to make sure that Parcelable doesn't break your common code, as this is Android only concept. 
For this, in your common code add

> expect interface Parcelable

as well as:

> @UseExperimental(ExperimentalMultiplatform::class)
>   @OptionalExpectation @Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
>   @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
>   expect annotation class Parcelize()

will look like this:
[image]

Then in your Android source set, typealias in actual:

> actual typealias Parcelable = android.os.Parcelable
>
> actual typealias Parcelize = kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

In other source sets (such as iOS), just put this into actual:

> actual interface Parcelable

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the idea on using Parcelable instead, I gave it a try but I am not able to get the dependencies _android.os.Parcelable_ and _kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize_ to work in my MPP module even though I'm including the plugin _com.android.library_

Comment: @Lucho did you include ktx (Kotlin android extensions) - parcelize is part of that

Comment: Yes i did unfortunetly

Comment: @Lucho please see here, this is my multiplatform project, using parcelize, all working - build file for the common here, https://github.com/dmitrish/kinsight-multiplatform/blob/master/SharedCode/build.gradle.kts, you can look at the whole project as well (although its pretty big). Some detail is off, the principle is solid and working for me

Comment: After a few tweaks with the gradle script i got it working now, thx for help! I wont set this as answer as the original question was how to get it to work with serialization, i'll give u a +1 though

Comment: glad it worked. it actually does answer your question precisely - you cannot make it work with serialization, period, and using parcelize is the only way to achieve what you want. but up to you whether to accept or not.

Comment: @Lucho what tweaks did you have to make to the Gradle script to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

1. The new **Kotlinx** `Serializable`:

   - This library is designed to work with transmitting data between your app and its backend (cloud server), **Not For Transmitting Data Within Android App.** See offcial answer [here](https://twitter.com/murtazakhussain/status/1060237821405995015).

---

2. The old **Java** `Serializable` and **Android** `Parcelable`:

   - **Java** `Serializable` is slower than **Android** `Parcelable`, see [this](https://medium.com/@shibuprasad008/serializable-vs-parcelable-in-android-773ed4330401) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable).
   - **Kotlin Parcelize** plugin simplifys the setup of **Android** `Parcelable`, see [this](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize). Just need the annotaion and extends from it (for being recognized as `Custom Parcelable` by `safe args`).