# How is it possible to create a fragment with an Object parameter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to create a Fragment, and have a complex type (MyClass) as its parameter.
The [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) does not really mention it. I was able to find some examples with `Bundle`, but those only contain simple parameters, like `String` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static method named `getInstance()` or `createInstance()` or what ever you like for creating Fragment with some value

Java Version:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int arg) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("ARG", arg);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Kotlin Version:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    companion object {
       fun newInstance(arg: Int): MyFragment {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("ARG", arg)
            val fragment = MyFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

> I was able to find some examples with Bundle, but those only contain
> simple parameters, like String and Integer.

To pass custom object in `Bundle` you can use make your class [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) or [`Serializable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable). For Parcelable you can use [`putParcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putParcelable(java.lang.String,%2520android.os.Parcelable)) method to store your object in Bundle.

For `Parcelable` and `Serializable` in Android check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647471/1292557).

You will find some **plugin** in Android Studio that will auto generate `Parcelable` implementation code for your class

Another approach is convert your object to String using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and put that String in Bundle.

For `Gson` check [this post](https://medium.com/@theblackcat102/passing-object-between-activity-using-gson-7dfa11d74e06)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably serializing the complex class and deserializing it again in the fragment.

So something like

```
bundle.putString("object_key", gson.toJson(yourClassInstance));
```

And then deserialize it with

```
Type yourClassType = new TypeToken<YourClass>() {}.getType();
YourClass yourClassInstance = gson.fromJson(bundle.getString("object_key"), yourClassType);
```

or, if your class isn't generic:

```
gson.fromJson(bundle.getString("object_key"), YourClass.class);
```

For more information, see the [Gson docs](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Object-Examples)