# Exception serializing abstract class

Tags: java, android, serialization, serializable

Im trying to develop a little android game and i'm having a hard time understanding how can i surpass this problem.

What i'm trying to do is send data between activities.To achieve that i'm using the intent extras.
The data that im trying to send is an ArrayList<Item

Item.java

```
public abstract class Item implements Serializable {

    private String fieldA;
    private int fieldB;
      
     *getters and setters*
    
    abstract void use();
}
```

the use method will be different on each item so thats why im using abstract

e.g creation item

```
Item hpPotion = new Item() {
            @Override
            public void use() {
                player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + 10)
            }
        };
```

and then im getting an error when starting the new Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this,BagActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("items",player.getItems());
                    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent,options);
```

StackTrace:

````
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.decisions, PID: 22018
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.decisions.HistoryActivity$7)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2116)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1886)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1095)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1835)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:978)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1629)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1047)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10871)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3887)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5405)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:237)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:208)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:166)
        at com.example.decisions.HistoryActivity$2.onClick(HistoryActivity.java:96)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7559)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7536)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28700)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.decisions.HistoryActivity
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2111)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1886) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:1095) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1835) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:978) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1629) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1047) 
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10871) 
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3887) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727) 
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5405) 
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574) 
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:237) 
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:208) 
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:166) 
        at com.example.decisions.HistoryActivity$2.onClick(HistoryActivity.java:96) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7559) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7536) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28700) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
    ```

What would be the best approach to solve my problem?

Thank you all
````

Comment: "I'm getting an error" is not a problem description.

Comment: Post the entire stack trace

Comment: Use parcelable instead of serializable, it's optimized for android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Comment: @cmak Meh, the difference is minor, and Serializable is a lot easier.  It's rare for the difference to matter

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to serialize an `Activity`, either directly or indirectly (something you're trying to Serialize has a reference to an `Activity`).  That's not possible, because `Activity` does not implement Serializable.  To properly implement Serializable, all of your member variables must either be primitives or implement Serializable themselves.

Edit:  If `Item` is a subclass of `Activity`, it may be picking up the implicit parent reference.  In that case, make it a static class.

Comment: If `Item` is a subclass of `Activity` there is something seriously wrong with the design, but making it a static class won't fix anything, even if it's possible.

Comment: @user207421 I agree it shouldn't be, but if for some reason it is (most likely due to a newbie not knowing how subclasses work and just adding it in one file), then making it static would work-  it removes the inherent parent reference which causes the problem.

Comment: No it doesn't. Making a class `static` implies that it was otherwise 'inner', and therefore had an implicit reference *to the outer object.* Making it `static` will fix that, but it won't change its behaviour w.r.t. the parent class, to which BTW there is no 'implicit reference'. In any case the exception names `HistoryActivity`, not `Item`.

Comment: @user207421 So you've just proven you completely don't understand Java and inner classes.  A static inner class removes the implicit reference to the parent class.  That's the entire purpose of a static inner class.  It's basically telling the compiler "I know this is an inner class, but I don't want it to be able to access variables of the parent, its here only for organizational purposes"

Comment: No, *you've* proven that you are confused between inheritance and inner classes. Your answer talks about `Item` being a subclass of `Activity` rather than an inner class of it. All the other stuff you claim I don't know I have already stated here. NB ['static inner' is a contradiction in terms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). NB 2 It is possible, although probably pointless, to serialize a subclass of `Activity` as long as the subclass `implements Serializable`. Your answer and comments are seriously confused.

Comment: `Serializable` is an interface, so I don't know what you mean by 'subclass of `Serializable`', nor by 'generalize' it, but if you mean 'serialize a subclass of a non-serializable class' you can indeed do that, and it is done every day: *vide* the fact that `java.lang.Object` is not `Serializable`. You should have corrected your mistyping, at several points, not just one, instead of arguing and especially instead of shooting the messenger. Abuse reported.